# The event_timestamp value from firebase comes from the future time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase that linked to BigQuery to send events data. It creates tables in the old partition way where the date is part of the table name.

Firebase creates a schema that has `event_timestamp` and `event_date`.

In the documentation of [Firebase schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en&visit_id=638403950909555044-790090463&rd=1) it is written that event_timestamp is "The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client."

Event_timetsamp values for the current day or the past can be found in the `event_intraday_DATE_INFO` tables. I wanted to get the date and time information by checking the `TIMESTAMP_MICROS()` of the `event_timestamp` value coming from Firebase, but I saw `event_timestamp` values from the future time that do not belong to that day in the `event_intraday` tables.

Example query:

```
SELECT event_timestamp, TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)
FROM 'project_name.analytics_xxx.events_intraday_20240107'
```

Example events_intraday_20240107 table:

[image]

The event_timestamp value coming from Firebase comes in integer format, and when viewed with the `TIMESTAMP_MICROS()` control on BigQuery, it can be seen that it contains future time information.

If this event_timestamp value comes from the client, is it because the future time is received incorrectly from the sending device? What could be the reason for this? Why does future time information come from?

Comment: Please update your post with a specific example of the event and how the event was generated. Not enough details to know if this is a Google bug or if your code is interpreting the data incorrectly.

Comment: The query example used has been added

Comment: My request is to show how the request is generated, not what you logged.

Comment: Please update your post with a specific example of the event and how the event was generated. Update your post and not via comments.

Comment: Post updated to detail event_timestamp value

Comment: Perhaps you do not understand my request. Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update our post. I am trying to help you but your details are not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Information updated in detail